# How do I switch my Wordpress to point to Parked Domain?

Tags: domain-mapping

Bought some hosting with BlueHost, and when I signed up, I carelessly choose 'DekhoForum' as my domain name.

I proceeded to setup a [website](http://www.dekhoforum.com) with Wordpress 3.1 at the root folder of that address.

Realised that my company had already reserved some domain names with a different provider, that were more suitable.

So we got those domains forwarded to the BlueHost nameservers.

So.  I now have a parked domain for dekho.com.au as shown in my cPanel:
[image: BlueHost]

If I hit the parked domain, it does take me to my Wordpress install.

However, when I click on subsequent links, it will take me to URLs like:
*dekhoforum.com/page=1*
I would prefer it to retain:
*dekho.com.au/page=1*

How do I fix this?

Seeing as I am still in the early stages of my development, I would like to iron this issue out from the beginning to avoid any headaches further down the track.

I am not sure if this is something I should be changing under the Wordpress settings or something from within my BlueHost cPanel?

Comment: Side note - i imagine my Qs will be fairly amateur, but thats what you want on a Q&A site, right?  Happy to convert to C-Wiki, if this is a FAQ, and the Q&A need tweaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Changing the Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Changing The Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) codex entry.